# Using polly to generate audio from LLM output

Tags: stream, mp3, amazon-polly

These days LLM (like GPT) start producing output few characters/words at a time. So although complete response can take 2-5 seconds or more, the partial characters start getting streamed almost in 0.5 sec and keep coming every 0.1 sec.

I would want to use polly to generate speech from the output of LLM. I dont want to wait till end of response, instead, as soon I get few words (say every 5-6 words or I see punctuation), i want to call polly, get the stream, and play this on audio on html.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You probably *don't* actually want to do this.  Polly can interpret a sentence to get the proper intonation and phrasing.  If you just shove words at it, it won't make much sense.  You'll want to split at least on a sentence boundary, and then you're going to start running into language issues.

Comment: Assuming I want to do this at sentence boundary. Which would still save me a second or two, how to do this @Brad